# cas-gradle-overlay-template-master gradle bootrun error

Tags: gradle, cas

```
dependencies {
compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-webapp-tomcat:${project.'cas.version'}@war"
    if (!project.hasProperty('bootiful')) {
        // Other dependencies may be listed here...
    } else {
        println "Running CAS in Bootiful mode; all dependencies except the CAS web application are ignored."
    }
}
```

this gradle bootrun success

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-webapp-tomcat:${project.'cas.version'}@war"
    if (!project.hasProperty('bootiful')) {
        compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-jdbc:${project.'cas.version'}"
        compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-jdbc-drivers:${project.'cas.version'}"
    // Other dependencies may be listed here...
    } else {
        println "Running CAS in Bootiful mode; all dependencies except the CAS web application are ignored."
    }
}
```

this error message
[gradle scans](https://scans.gradle.com/s/umezwkplhzmcu)

The code works normally when the code is not changed.

But any reliance would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the README file of the project:

> Be careful with this method of deployment. bootRun is not designed to work with already executable WAR artifacts such that CAS server web application. YMMV. Today, uses of this mode ONLY work when there is NO OTHER dependency added to the build script and the cas-server-webapp is the only present module.